# How to execute a specific command on opening a terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, scripts

I would like to execute the shell command "cmatrix" whenever I open a terminal. How to go about achieving this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add `cmatrix` command in your `~/.bashrc` file located at home folder:

```
echo 'cmatrix' >> ~/.bashrc
```

**NOTE:** Please ensure that you use `>>`, the append operator. If you use `>`, it will replace your whole `~/.bashrc` with `cmatrix` only.

Comment: Please make **very sure** that you use `>>` (two arrows!) and not only *`>`*. Otherwise this will replace your file and delete the old one. You could also open the file with any text editor and manually append the line.

Comment: @snoop i would safely use $gedit ~/.bashrc. Thanks for the caution :)

Comment: Of course this is a good answer, but just to be exact, this way the command will be executed each time a `bash` instance is spawned by the user, so not only in `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Or you can edit the .bashrc file with `gedit ~/.bashrc &`

Answer (score 7):

Because you tagged your question with `gnome-terminal`, you can also use a a custom command for your `gnome-terminal` profile. 
The advantage, the command is executed only for a specific profile and not always when the bash is started somewhere.

But first install `dconf-editor`. If you make a mistake in the steps below, you will need this tool

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Now open `gnome-terminal` and edit your profile settings and use this command

```
sh -c "cmatrix;bash"
```

as you can see in the screenshot below. If you don't use the bash, replace `bash` with your shell.

[image]

---

If you made a mistake and `gnome-terminal` is unusable, use use `dconf-editor` to correct your problem:

Start `dconf-editor` and navigate to the settings of GNOME terminal and change the values for `custom-command` and `use-custom-command` in the settings for your `gnome-terminal` profile

Comment: If the user makes a mistake, they may not be able to pull up a terminal in the first place.

Comment: @Kevin therefore the last part in my answer.

Comment: Where are they supposed to type `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`?

Comment: @kevin good point, thank you. I have changed my answer.

Comment: @kevin But there is always tty1 and so on. ;)

Comment: Sure, but you have to tell them about that or they won't know to use it.

Comment: use exec: `sh -c "ls -A;exec bash"` to avoid create another process

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Fedora with XFCE desktop. I encountered problems when Fedora boots, by using the solution provided by @snoop, and the solution provided by @AB gave me the "Failed to execute child process (no such file or directory)" error. Searching for a solution, finally I used a script saved as `~/bin/cmatrix_launcher.sh` with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmatrix -baC cyan
/bin/bash
```

throwing then it as a custom command in the `xfce4-terminal` settings (screenshot attached)

[image: xfce4-terminal with custom command]

Comment: `[ "xfce4-terminal" ]` is always true.